# Java SimpleDateFormat returning null, but only on second call

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    String datetoparse = "7/1/2003 00:02:53";
    Date date = formatter.parse(datetoparse, pp);
    System.out.println(date.toString());
    date = formatter.parse(datetoparse, pp);
    System.out.println(date.toString());
}
```

The format call returns the correct value on the first call.  But why does it return null on the second call (where I am parsing the same string as in the first call)?

Comment: `public Date parse(String text, ParsePosition pos)` > _A Date parsed from the string. In case of error, returns null._ [Javadoc link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, you're using a `ParsePosition`.  The first `parse` call updates the `ParsePosition` to past the date used in the parse.  The second `parse` call has nothing to parse.  That's an error, [and `parse` returns `null`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29).

Just use [the inherited `parse` method without a `ParsePosition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Or for the sake of justifying call `pp.setIndex(0)` :)

Comment: Thanks rgettman, you are correct.  I thought parse() required a ParsePosition parameter, but only the method overloaded in SimpleDateFormat does.  The parse method in parent class DateFormat does not require it so I simply removed the parameter and it works now.